# Message Event Handler Exist or not in window object

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page in HTML that contains iframe. If message comes from iframe I have to handle it. But how to check if message event handler exist or not? My code is

```
$(window).on('message',function(e){
console.log(e.originalEvent.data);
});
```

When button is clicked this code set message event handler. But when again clicked - again message handler get added. Is there any method to know if in window object is message event handler present or not. Please guideline. I can't use global variable in my case. If it's possible to get event handler from window object then please explain the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $("body").text("click");
    // `message` `handler`
    window.msgHandler = function (e) {
        if (e.origin === "http://fiddle.jshell.net") {
            console.log(e, e.data);
        };
    };
    window.addEventListener('message', msgHandler, false);
    var iframe = $("<iframe>", {
            "width": "150px",
            "height": "150px",
            "target": "_top"
    });
    $(iframe).one("load", function (e) {
        var _data = $(e.target)[0].nodeName + " loaded at " + e.timeStamp;
        window.postMessage(_data, "http://fiddle.jshell.net");

        $(e.target)
            .contents()
            .find("html")
            .html("<html><body><div>" 
                  + _data 
                  + "</div><br /></body></html>");
        return false
    });
    var loadFrame = function (e) {
        // if in window object is message event handler present or not
        console.log("msgHandler" in window
                    ? [ window.msgHandler
                      , window.msgHandler.toString()
                      , typeof window.msgHandler ] 
                    : false);
        $(e.target)
            .text("")
            .append($(iframe))
    };

    $(window).one("click", loadFrame);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9xC27/