# Running a jQuery function with HTML5 WebSockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I recently started messing around with HTML5 WebSockets and was wondering if it's possible to run jQuery functions through them.

For my example, I would have 2 web pages (on the same domain).  PageA.html would have a button, that when clicked, would run a function on PageB.html - any users connected to PageB.html will see the function run (perhaps an animation).

What would the best way to go about this be?

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a connection between pageA and pageB? You cannot do this without a server.  Do you have a server setup for this?

Comment: Yes, they would be connected.  I believe I could use something like node.js  with Socket.IO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24317036/ , http://stackoverflow.com/a/24353675/ ?